# What type of employees are "obliged to join a union as a condition of employment" in New York?

Tags: united-states, employment, new-york, labor-union

This is an excerpt from an article explaining why Amazon is reconsidering opening its headquarters in New York:

> New York is a pro-labor city, whereas Virginia is a right-to-work state where employees cannot be obliged to join a union as a condition of employment.

In New York, what type of employees are "obliged to join a union as a condition of employment"?

Answer (score 9):

Most notably in construction and entertainment.

In construction, many companies have closed shop or union shop contracts whereby you either have to join a union, or pay the equivalent sum of money. https://therealdeal.com/issues_articles/the-state-of-the-construction-union/

In entertainment, you must be a member of the actors guild to perform in a union theatre, and Guild members cannot perform in non-union performances.

Comment: NYC is also known for extremely an extremely strong stagehand union - don't know what it's really called - is that also closed shop?  (I guess it's considered 'entertainment' also?)

Comment: And while public sector workers are not technically obliged to “join”, [they do have to pay dues](https://www.nytimes.com/2008/07/24/nyregion/24unions.html).